# OneDrive: AutoSave does not save Documents directory to cloud

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I have the following directory structure:

- **C:\Users\MyName\Documents**
- **C:\Users\MyName\OneDrive**

In my OneDrive Autosave settings I have selected "OneDrive" in the "Choose where you want to save your documents and pictures" setting for Documents

By my understanding, I thought this would mean that anything I save in my **C:\Users\MyName\Documents** folder would automatically be synched up to my OneDrive?

However, I do not see this occurring. Therefore, I'm wondering what may be going wrong here? Am I understanding this feature correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If the OneDrive Auto save settings are enabled, the `Documents` & `Pictures` folders are redirected here:

`C:\Users\%username%\OneDrive\Documents`

`C:\Users\%username%\OneDrive\Pictures`

Anything saved in the above location is automatically synced to the cloud, assuming that OneDrive client is started/running.

Comment: Hmmm that was my understanding too, but we are not observing that behaviour!

Comment: Pls note the folder path (Myname\OneDrive\Documents) above. It's different from the path you mentioned (Myname\Documents) in the original post.